# Question: UCSC hub: autoscale option for multiwig track

Tags: ucsc, bigwig

I am making a hub on UCSC Genome Browser and I am aiming to display multiple bigWig files as a single track (multiwig container). I decided to use the autoscale option because I wanted a dynamic scale: y axis changing depending on the maximum values in the current observed window.

However, I am confused as to how to the relationship between:

- autoscale on and viewLimits
- autoscale on and type bigWig <#> <#>

For the "type" option, the official documentation mentions that: "The remote data files of type bigWig must declare the expected signal range for the data"

**So my question is, are the following assumptions correct**:

- If I have autoscale on, I don't need to specify viewLimits
- I still have to specify "type bigWig" but you no longer have to put a range (i.e. the <#> <#>)

If this is correct, my trackDb.txt file will look as such:

```
track data
container multiWig
configurable on
shortLabel label data
longLabel long label data
visibility full
priority 1
type bigWig
autoScale on
aggregate transparentOverlay
windowingFunction mean
showSubtrackColorOnUi on

    track sample1
    bigDataUrl path/to/sample1.bw
    shortLabel s_sample1
    longLabel s_sample1
    type bigWig
    visibility full
    alwaysZero on
    priority 120
    color 220,180,180
    parent data on

    track sample2
    bigDataUrl path/to/sample2.bw
    shortLabel s_sample2
    longLabel s_sample2
    type bigWig
    visibility full
    alwaysZero on
    priority 120
    color 220,180,180
    parent data on

    etc
```

Comment: Apologies, just updated my question, I hope it's clearer.